# Virtualbox ssh (Connection Failed EHOSTUNREACH)

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, virtualbox, port-forwarding, android

I am trying to set up a ssh server on Linux through virtualbox on a Windows 8.1 (windows has wireless connection). I have installed openssh and got it running. I've set up rules for the inbound and outbound allowing port 22 on my windows firewall. Steps I used for port forwarding:

(Centurylink Modem Configuration)
1. Select device = 192.168.0.16
2. Starting port = 22
3. Ending port = 22
4. Protocol = TCP
5. Remote port = [All IP Addresses].

I have accessed ssh on a local network. I've went to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and port 22 was open. When I tried to connect to root@my.external.IP:22 on Android JuiceSSH it returned:

"Connection Failed
failed to connect to /my.external.ip (port 22): connect failed: 
EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

Do you want to retry?"

Comment: Please be more specific for this statement: " I've port forwarded port 22 to Virtualbox IP (192.168.0.16)" Also you should describe how your windows machine is connected to internet

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I shut down everything and rebooted the server and it worked. I guess the server couldn't change stuff while its running? Learned something new though, fun project.